# json_decode into a select/option menu

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I'm trying to get to decode the following:

```
 $options = Input::get('options');
 $product->options = json_encode($options);
```

Within a select/option dropdown but when I use json_decode like so:

```
 <select name="options">
     <option>{{ $item->options }}</option>
 </select>
```

(I'm Laravel blade here)

When I view it the browser I get the following image - http://d.pr/i/D8z7

It's also i a foreach loop too.

So what I'm I doing wrong or how can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop it.

```
 <select name="options">
     @foreach ($item->options as $option)
     <option>{{ $option }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: Getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() based on what you put.

Comment: Would this be because I'm calling @foreach($products as $item) further up the code

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Make sure `$item->options` is an array but not a string first.

Comment: It's a string so how would i convert it first ?

Comment: Tried this: 

      foreach (json_decode($item->options) as $option)
        <option>{{ $option }}</option>
      endforeach 

But still getting invalid arugment.

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II So what is the result of `json_decode($item->options) `?

Comment: ErrorException

Array to string conversion

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Then it's an array, but you say it's a string at first.

Comment: I didnt say it was a string but it's not showinf up in the select correctly.

Comment: upon doing the following:

var_dump(json_decode($item->options)) i get this:

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Bare Filter - £200.00' (length=22)
  1 => string 'Filter with Standard Media - £235.00' (length=37)
  2 => string 'Filter with K1 upgrade - £265.00' (length=33)
  3 => string 'Bare Filter - £285.00' (leng

Comment: So how would i get the to function correctly in a select menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Any idea's anyone, really need to get this sorted. it looks like when i json_encode thats fine i just need to return the json correctly into the select menu